# Does a commentary exist for the Linga Purana?

Tags: puranas, commentary

Are commentaries available for the following Puranas?

1. Linga Purana
2. Shiva Purana
3. Devi Purana
4. Skanda Purana

Do these books have commentaries?

Comment: Yes these books have commentaries

Comment: Can you mention

Comment: Any one can mention

Comment: @DarkKnight Could you please tell the names and the authors of these commentaries?
I know about a commentary to Liṅga Purāṇa named Śivatoṣiṇī by Gaṇeśanāṭu and there's a commentary on Devībhāgavata Purāṇa by Nīlakaṇṭha. Sūta saṁhitā of Skanda Purāṇa has a commentary named Tātparyadīpikā by Mādhavācārya.

Comment: The above message might be helpful for you @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud